# How to keep html new line in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading a column content using

```
$("#myText").text($.trim($(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('.mytext).text()));
```

However, though there is multiple new lines, the text being copied doesn`t show the lines as new line but rather shows it as a line in the textrea.

if my text is

```
Line 1

Line 2

Line 3
```

it's appearing as

```
Line1Line2Line3
```

Comment: C'mon this would be an easy jsfiddle to make. You really need to use that when asking a question. We can't really cain a solid hold on your problem since we can't see it and we can't test different methods. Therefore, since you didn't use an example, all the answers will be guesses at best since we can't actually test them without a jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes a js fiddle is nice to have, but I think it is a clearly defined question and therefore, a fiddle is not entirely necessary.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer if he made a fiddle. It would take him like two minutes and it would make my job as the answerer a lot easier since I had a way to test my solution using his specific source code.

Comment: fiddles are nice but shouldn't be mandatory since if it was just a fiddle with no code in the question there would be people complaining that they had to visit an external link to answer the question and also that external links can change rendering the question useless etc

Comment: @martincarlin87, it's not mandatory to post a Fiddle, but in this case it would be useful to see what text he's selecting (where it's coming from, how it's formatted) and to try out different possible solutions. Also to point out, and/or explain, any implementation or syntax errors. Ideally there'd be a Fiddle demo *and* representative code in the question: there's no mutually exclusive rule, Fiddle ***or*** code...we really can, and hope to, have both.

Comment: @David Thomas, I agree with you but I just thought that Mark was being a bit harsh on the asker here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your code look like this `Line 1<br/>Line 2<br/>Line 3<br/>`? If you can format the html then try to format it like this:

```
Line 1<br/>
Line 2<br/>
Line 3<br/>
```

If you can't format html than you have to use `html` method and if `#myText` is textarea then you should use `val` method to set its value.

If you can't format html then your code should look like this to work:

```
$("#myText").val(
    $.trim(
        $(this).closest('tr').next('tr')
            .find('.mytext').html().replace('<br/>', '/r/n')
    )
);
```

with the replace part a little richer to address more general case.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you text in the table cell you have content like:

```
Line 1<br/>
Line 2<br/>
Line 3<br/>
```

Or in separate divs, or ny other method to splitting it on separate lines. 
But `textarea` doesn't handle all html tags, it displays just plain text. And for separating line it uses `\n\r` whitch means new lane and carriage return.

Try to replace `<br />` to `\n\r`. But it will helps only if your lines in the column splitted by `<br />`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#myText").html($.trim($(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('.mytext').text()));
```

You used .text which only records what it says: "text". You need to use .html to keep the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem might be coming from your trim function.  You are trimming all the newlines.  To be able to trim it and have a newline at the end, you could manually put that newline in there:

```
$("#myText").text($.trim($(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('.mytext').text()) + "\r\n");
```

And after reviewing this for several minutes, I have to agree this would be easier to troubleshoot with a jsfiddle.  It's not totally clear exactly what's going on.  We have to make a lot of assumptions about how you are using this code.  E.g., we are assuming that

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

is actually

```
Line 1<br>
Line 2<br>
```

which should actually work the way you expect.